# Create an index tree (balanced BST) from a linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, indexing, binary-search-tree, doubly-linked-list

I have a Doubly Linked List which I want to create an index tree from to increase random access performance. The nodes in the linked list don't have a unique identity and can be any instance of a derived Node object which has a next and a previous reference. For increasing the performance of random access to the nodes i.e. to a specific index of the list, I want to add an index tree on top of this list. For example, the user may want to retrieve the third node of the list and then the 5th node. 
I want to know if there is any solution already proposed to this problem.

One solution I have in my mind is to use a special type of a binary tree in which each node keeps a number. This number will show how many nodes are kept in its children references. For example if the root node's number is 5, this means the list has 5 nodes. Imagine the left node's number is 3 and the right node's number is 2, this means the first 3 nodes are in the left part and the remaining 2 are in the right part. This will go on to the leaves which will have number 1 which will point to the list's nodes. The desired tree is to be a balanced BST.

Another way is to consider an index of a node in the list as its data (so it is sorted) and use something like [Convert Sorted List to Balanced Binary Search Tree](http://leetcode.com/2010/11/convert-sorted-list-to-balanced-binary.html). In addition, add a reference to the actual list node in the tree nodes so the node with number (data) 2 is referring to the second node in the list.
I want to know what the fastest way is to create and maintain this tree from a linked list?

Thank you in advance

EDIT:
Because of the memory concerns and also persistence requirements, I have to use a Linked List and not just an array of the references. This part is already done so consider a Linked List starting from a head. In addition, you have access to the tail and number of items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy answer: **An array of pointers to nodes in the list.**  To get the 3rd node, just index the third element in the array.  If you do this, you will no longer need previous and next members in your nodes; just go to the previous or next element of the array.

If you still want to maintain a dynamic linked list, just use a List<Node> (C#) or vector<Node *> (C++)  instead of the array, so elements can be inserted and deleted.

Comment: Memory is an issue here and I can not just keep the references in an array and that is the main reason we want to keep the elements in a linked list instead of an array. I need to implement my own Linked List and not use List<Node> or Vector because I need to have persistence also. However, this was not my question and this part is already done.